# No color using windows SSH terminal on Pi4

Tags: ssh, pi-4, terminal

I have a Pi3 and PiZero. When I open up a Terminal window in Windows and SSH into the Pi4, the text is not color coded like on my Pi3 and PiZ. It appears that the .bashrc files are the same per a different post. 
What can be different?

Comment: What program are you using on Windows to link to the Pi?  My iPad allows three emulations and only one of them is in colour.

Comment: I always uncomment the line `force_color_prompt=yes` in .bashrc

Comment: I am just using the windows command processor. I have a pi Zero and the the prompt on SSH login is pi@raspberry (green) and ~$ (blue). I checked the .bashrc files and they are identical. I start the SSH session the same way with both.

Comment: I also just tried PowerShell, it has colored text for my ssh login to the Pi4

Comment: Looking around it seems that there are so many possible fixes but most do not seem to work. I am really wondering about root cause.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is not a real way to diagnose this issue. After changing the color prompts per above in both the pi directory and another, nothing seemed to work.

Slow wifi and not able to connect continued to plague me so I thought there was a hw issue starting to develop. Long story short, I dnloaded the latest release and reloaded it. Color works and Wifi is stable and fast.